# Using pthread for a while(1) loop in c++?

Tags: c++, class, pthreads

i have a question about how to change my written program in c++
like the picture below.

Actually my program starts. And if I want to start the function e.g. `test::test1`
which is a `while(1)` loop which never ends, the program below the loop will never be run.

So I searched a lot and I got the topic pthread for my problem.

But I really dont know, how to change my program...

I got following files:

```
main.cpp
test.h
test.cpp
```

Here is the `while(1)-Loop out` of `test.cpp`
The function `save()` will open a database and saves value1-3, time, date.
I want the function `test::test1()` starts up when the main programm initialize the class test.

Does anyone has a clue, how to change my program?

```
 void test::test1()
    {


        double i = 1;

    while(1)
    {

        i=i;
        save(i, value1(), value2(), value3(), time(), date());
        i++;

        usleep( DELAY * 1000000 );

    }

Here is my image
http://abload.de/img/unbenanntfquwl.png
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to to achieve. Do you want to tearn test::test1() into a pthread ?

Comment: C++ has its own threads, std::thread, which you should use by default. Search for according tutorials online or discussions here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really restricted to pthreads the following might help.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 
#include <unistd.h> 

class test { 
public: 
    void save(...) {}; 
    void test1() { 
        double i = 1; 

        while(true) 
        { 
            save(i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
            i++; 

            std::cerr << " ** " << std::endl; 
            usleep( 1000000 ); 

        } 
    } 

    static void * run(void * arg ) { 
        ((test *)arg)->test1();
        return NULL; 
    } 
}; 


int main() 
{ 
    pthread_t thr; 
    test tst; 
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL,test::run,&tst); 
    pthread_join(thr,NULL); 
    return 1; 
}
```

The most important part for a running pthread is a pointer to a C-Style function which take a void * argument. Non static C++ member functions always take **this** as a hidden argument so they are no direct candidate for a pthread. I always create a static run(...) method which explicitly takes the pointer to the object and forwards the call to the non-static member function.

If you are allowed to use more modern C++ features I would follow @Ulrich Eckhardt and use the std::thread construct.

PS: Added missing retun statement in run(...)

Comment: Hi Oncaphillis,
thanks for your comment.
I copied your source into my program, but the compiler says:
|26|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token|
The line 26 is the following:
pthread_create(&thr, NULL,test::run,&tst);

An other question to your source. Do i have to put the while(true)-loop into the header file, like you did in your code?

Comment: @jollepe In my line 26 which is located in run(...) thre only was a missing return statement which my gcc silently accepts. I've updated the code and it just runs fine. Of course you have to link with the pthread lib. I didn't place the loop into a header, it's a self contained code blob based on your example. The layout simply is up to you. In essence pthread_create simply needs to know the address of the function to run.

Comment: I copied your correction into my program. But nevertheless the program doesn't compile. My line 26 is the following line of code:
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL,messen::run,&tst);

I copied this code at the beginning of my int main (), but after the initialization of the class.

    pthread_t thr;
    messen tst;
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL,messen::run,&tst);
    pthread_join(thr,NULL);

Added test.cpp with:

    static void * run(void * arg ) {
        ((messen *)arg)->messung();
        return NULL;
    }

And therefore i copy this code in the test.h

    static void * run(void * arg );

Comment: @jollepe It's really not easy to understand what you did, but taken as it is my code runs. If you paste my code into your program it's hard to understand what your line 26 might be.